# How to implement authentication and authorization SPA by using existing REST resources?

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, authorization, hottowel

I need to implement role based authentication and authorization on single page application that developed by using Angular js hottowel template. for authentication and authorizations i have already implemented REST resources. when pass the user details it will returns the user is valid or not.

I have done some R&Ds on this and most of people implemented that AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity. as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A) article .

But my requirement is use existing REST resources to validate user and implement authentication and authorizations on angular js single page application. Please advice me to implement correct way to achieve this. 
Thank you

Comment: We do this a good bit using JWTs. You can generate a public/private RSA key pair and sign your jwt server side (I've done this using nodejs, I'm sure there are resources to do this for any other server technology as well, or you can do this yourself relatively easily by RSA encrypting your payload and then base64 encoding. On the angular side again this could be done with something custom or there is an Angular-JWT module available I've also used.  This gives you authentication and session management as well using local storage and proper expiration dates in your jwt payload.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHalbert i will check on that

Comment: @JohnHalbert i have done some R&Ds on JWT with Angular js. There is also need to generate a token from the server side. i haven't clear idea regarding the generating token in server side.please provide any link or articles to reffer

Comment: I am not very familiar with ASP.NET and Owin. I found this, but maybe you already have as well http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/ - I have done this using NodeJS and the Jwt-simple module. Sorry I can't give more specific advice for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of accomplishing what you are trying to do. A simple one, that uses jsonwebtoken can be found here: https://github.com/renanbet/node-rest-token. It is still an ongoing work. I hope it helps.